# WinSCP batch script - %ERRORLEVEL% always = 0?

Tags: batch-file, winscp

REM ---### FTP_Batch ###---

```
@echo off
```

REM Get first line record and store in %%A

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (FTP_Account_with_Password_and_EOL.txt) do (
```

REM Run WinSCP with %%A as open connection

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="c:\temp\WinSCP.log" /loglevel=1 /ini=nul ^
    /command ^
    "%%A" ^
    "ls" ^
    "exit"
%WINSCP_RESULT% = %ERRORLEVEL%

    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
      echo Error 
      echo %ERRORLEVEL% %%A 

    ) else (
      echo Success %ERRORLEVEL% %%A 
      echo Winscp Result %WINSCP_RESULT%
    )
    pause
    )

ENDLOCAL
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

Comment: ---### FTP_Account_with_Password_and_EOL.txt ###---

open ftp://Login1:Password@ftp.xxxxxx.com/;

open ftp://Login2:Password@ftp.xxxxxx.com/;

open ftp://Login3:Password@ftp.xxxxxx.com/;

open ftp://Login4:Password@ftp.xxxxxx.com/;
...

Comment: Please, show us the simplest batch file you can reproduce the problem with. And format your post to make ir readable.

Comment: Use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%`. And `set "WINSCP_RESULT=!ERRORLEVEL!"`. Read http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html